# How to read the Bundle version from PList?

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to read the app's bundled plist file, I am wanting to pull the value for Bundle version.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

See [Getting the Bundle’s Info.plist Data](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH104-123093).

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey];
```

should get you the bundle version.

Comment: Some more information can be found in (a duplicate):
[How can I check the bundle version of our application programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657477/how-can-i-check-the-bundle-version-of-our-application-programmatically)

Comment: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];` will get you the short version string as shown in the answer below (just posting the objc version)

Comment: hi OleB, the document link is outdated

Answer (score 16):

In Swift you can use:

```
let bundleVersion = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKeykCFBundleVersionKey as String) as! String
```

or:

```
let bundleVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?[kCFBundleVersionKey as String] as! String
```

If you want the short bundle versions string, you can use:

```
let shortBundleVersion = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey:"CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#define APP_VERSION [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleVersionKey]
```