# How can I check the bundle version of our application programmatically?

Tags: iphone

I have made an application and I have installed it on my iphone, but I want to check my application bundle version programatically. How can that be done?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
NSString *versionString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleVersionKey];
```

Comment: How would one make a macro out of this?

Comment: #define APP_VERSION [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleVersionKey];

Comment: no semicolon at the end of the macro. and it should probably be called BUNDLE_VERSION.

Answer (score 16):

Here are some macros:

```
#define BUNDLE_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[NSBundle mainBundle]     objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString*) kCFBundleVersionKey] compare:v  options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define BUNDLE_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)              ([[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString*) kCFBundleVersionKey] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define BUNDLE_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString*) kCFBundleVersionKey] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define BUNDLE_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString*) kCFBundleVersionKey]  compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define BUNDLE_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString*) kCFBundleVersionKey] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)
```