# How to retrieve Bundle Version in a label from project test-Info.plist in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone

Here I'm pasting my codes where I want to retrieve Bundle version from my test-Info.plist.

```
@interface testViewController : UIViewController {
    UILabel *label;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet    UILabel *label;

@end

@implementation testViewController

@synthesize label;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test-info" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSString *versionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"v%d", [plistData objectForKey:@"Bundle version"]];

    label.text = versionString;
}

@end
```

But still I got null value where I'm wrong

Comment: You really should post only that part of code that is relevant to your question - it is hard to browse hundred lines of code to find it...

Comment: Also check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657477/how-to-check-bundle-version-for-our-application-by-programming/2657500

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read the Bundle version from PList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244985/how-to-read-the-bundle-version-from-plist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the plist path by doing this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test-info" ofType:@"plist"];
```

Comment: still i m getting null value in my label

Comment: `[plistData objectForKey:@"Bundle version"]` will return an `NSNumber`. Either use `@"v%@"` in the format string to convert the NSNumber (you should always use `%@` for Obj-C objects in format strings), or keep it as `@"v%d"` and use `[[plistData objectForKey:@"Bundle version"] intValue]` to convert the `NSNumber` into an `int`.

Answer (score 36):

The following line will retrieve the version for you

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

Comment: Also worth noting: the "Bundle Version" or `CFBundleVersion` equates to the app's build number. If you want the actual "x.y" string, use `CFBundleShortVersionString` instead.